# www request not completing on Android 9 (Pie) Unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a simple script which creates a www request in game to check which country this apk running. It was working fine before android 9 OS devices but failed on android 9 OS devices. My www.error is giving an unknown error string.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class GeoData : MonoBehaviour
{   
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetText());
    }

    IEnumerator GetText()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://ip-api.com/json");// I also changed www string but all in vein
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
           //above Android 8 os devices, its comes here and debug  "Unknow error"
            Debug.Log("Done with Error: " + www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Final data is ="+ www.text);
            string stringToSplit = www.text;
            char[] splitters = { ',', ':', '"' };
            string[] splittedString = stringToSplit.Split(splitters, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var item in splittedString)
            {
                Debug.Log(item); // Country is at 6th index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have figured out what was the problem..
A non-secure URL, and it's now prohibited in Android 9 Pie.
you can't request.
so URL must be sure like this (https)